# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry for user_id")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a certain model:

```
class Problem(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    problem_text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    wiki_answer = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, default='', blank=True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=False, unique=False)
```

And after adding more than one post written by one user Django raises an error even though a user is not supposed to be unique. Here is the full stack trace:

```
File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  226.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.         raise errorvalue

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  217.             res = self._query(query)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  378.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  341.         db.query(q)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  280.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'interview_questions_problem_user_id_105dd8d0_uniq'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/interview_questions/views.py" in post
  55.             post.save()

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  708.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  736.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  820.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  859.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1060.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  226.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.         raise errorvalue

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  217.             res = self._query(query)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  378.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  341.         db.query(q)

File "/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/venv/interview_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.7-py3.4-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  280.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /p/add/
Exception Value: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'interview_questions_problem_user_id_105dd8d0_uniq'")
```

Django version 1.9.5.

Here is the view for adding post form:

```
class AddView(View):
    template_name = 'interview_questions/add.html'
    form_class = ProblemForm
    success_url = '/'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = self.form_class(None)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'user': request.user})
        else:
            return redirect('interview_questions:index')

    # process data
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.pub_date = timezone.now()
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('interview_questions:index')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'user': request.user})
```

Comment: Full stacktrace please

Comment: @e4c5 added full stacktrace

Comment: please include views.py post save method.

Comment: @e4c5 added post view class from view.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens here:

```
"/Users/artemdremov/Documents/python/interview_project/interview_questions/views.py" in post
  55.             post.save()
```

And that's because you have this in your model.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=False, unique=False)
```

unique=False has no effect here because there can be exactly one entry here.

[OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
>   ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
>   will directly return a single object.

There are three solutions

1. Change your OneToOneField to a ForeignKey
2. In your form validation make sure that a record does not exist
3. When creating the form check if an entry already exists and then allo the user to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an answer just for better understanding of what causes this error. And why the reason is invisible.

Lets say we have an object, let me call it node

```
class Node(models.Model):
     next_node = models.OneToOneField("Node", blank = True, null=True)
     previous_node = models.OneToOneField("Node", blank = True, null=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = "Nodes Name")
```

Then in the interactive console. You can access it in terminal (linux, sorry not sure how windows works anymore) by python(3) manage.py shell. 
I have just done the test that replicates this integrity error.

```
>>>first_node = Node()
>>> first_node.save()
>>> second_node = Node()
>>> second_node.save()
>>> third_node = Node()
>>> third_node.save()
>>> fourth_node = Node()
>>> fourth_node.save()

>>> first_node.next_node = second_node
>>> second_node.previous_node= first_node
>>> first_node.save()
>>> second_node.save()
>>> second_node.next_node = third_node
>>> third_node.previous_node=second_node
>>> second_node.save()
>>> third_node.save()
>>> second_node.next_node= fourth_node
>>> fourth_node.previous_node=second_node
>>> second_node.save()
>>> fourth_node.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):                
File
"/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/sitepackages/django/db/
 backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
..........
..........
..........
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: 
(1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'previous_node_id'")
```

The reason why this error is being produced is because, 
We already assigned second node as a previous node of third node.
We are attempting to assign it as the previous_node of fourth node again.

This can be a problem if you only conscious of the forward relationship of second node i.e what second node is pointing to and you forget the reverse relationship.

I think the best solution to your answer given the nature of your model is to change the OneToOne relationship to ForeignKey (so that one user can write several problems).

If one user has to have one problem. Then everytime you save a problem as suggested in e4c5's 2nd solution, you have to ensure that no user is already owning the problem.

***This can be particularly important when you have to resave or re-factor a model. For example in the case where you are saving an old problem with a new user/another user or a new user with an old problem. In the latter for example, it might not occur to you, that a certain user is already pointing to that problem and you will crush into an integrity error.***

Answer (score 0):

**If want to handle Duplicate exception in Django read this**

**How to avoid Duplicate exception**

We can also avoid from this kind of exception first check Profile exist or not  then create Profile if not existed.

We can achieve this using get_or_create() method.

---

Many times we need to make unique fields or unique_together in Model to achieve some business logic.

**Example**

User and Profile (OneToOne relationship)

One Profile is created for per user.

**Handle Duplicate entry exception in Django:**

If user already created their profile again want to create then we can easily handle duplicate entry of profile like this.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

try:
   profile = Profile.objects.create(user=someuser,imageUrl= url )
except IntegrityError:
   pass
   #Handle your exception here
```